# I want to count the number of presses of the button(switch) before it executes

Tags: button, arduino, embedded

my code only executes the case 1. i need if i press 3 times. it will execute my case 3. thank you so much

```
int pushButton = 13;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pushButton, INPUT);
for(int pin=10;pin<=12;pin++){
  pinMode(pin,OUTPUT);
}
}

void loop() {
  int ctr=0;
  int buttonState = digitalRead(pushButton);


 if(buttonState ==1)
  {
    ctr+=1;   
    Serial.println(ctr);


  }
  switch (ctr) {
  case 1:
  Serial.println("00000000000000000000");
     blinking();
    break;
  case 2:
  Serial.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
    running();

    break;
  case 3:
    incremental();
  default: 
    Serial.println("push the button");
}



}



void blinking(){

    for(int z=0;z<=3;z++){
    for(int i=10;i<=12;i++){
      digitalWrite(i,HIGH);
    }delay(500);
    for(int i=10;i<=12;i++){
      digitalWrite(i,LOW);
    }delay(500);
    }

}

void running(){
 for(int z=0;z<=2;z++){ 
   for(int i=10;i<=12;i++){
     digitalWrite(i,HIGH);
     delay(500);
     digitalWrite(i,LOW);
  }   
 } 

}


void incremental(){
 for(int z=0;z<=2;z++){
    int d=1500;
   for(int i=10;i<=12;i++){
    digitalWrite(i,HIGH);
    delay(d); d-=500;
   }
   for(int i=10;i<=12;i++){
    digitalWrite(i,LOW);
   }delay(500);  
  } 


}
```

my code only executes the case 1. i need if i press 3 times. it will execute my case 3. thank you so much

Comment: You need to de-bounce the button, ie apply some simple digital filter to get rid of the electromechanical signal bounce that appears when you press any button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `int ctr=0` to `static int ctr=0`

It is the same thing as declare `ctr` with global scope.

It will not reset to `0` each time `loop` function is called.

Button debounce  should be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that ctr is assigned zero *every* time `loop()` runs, you also have the problem that if the button is held down, `ctr` will increment continuously, which may not be what you want. It also increments `ctr` past three, when the default case will run indefinitely.  It is not clear that you intended case 3 to fall-through to the default case; it is generally considered bad practice or a mistake, so worth a comment if it is deliberate.

The following code makes `ctr` static so it is nor always assigned zero, and increments `ctr` only when the button is pressed down, and will not increment it if it is merely held-down or stuck.  It also returns `ctr` to zero in the default case so you can cycle the states (which may not be your intent).  I have removed the debug output for clarity.

```
void loop() 
{
  static int ctr = 0 ;
  static bool button_down = false ;
  int button_state = digitalRead(pushButton) == 1 ;

  if( !button_down && button_state = 1 )
  {
    ctr++ ;
    button_down = true ;
  }
  else if( button_state = 0 )
  {
     button_down = false ;
  }

  switch( ctr ) 
  {
    case 1:
      blinking();
    break;

    case 2:
      running();
    break;

    case 3:
      incremental();
    break ;

    default: 
        ctr = 0 ;
    break ;
  }
}
```